# Find the sum of columns even if the columns doesn't exist add zeros with it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following dataset:

```
coll1    col2    col3 
  2        3      4
  5        6      7
  8        9      1
```

I want to generate a another columns Let's say total, if I want to write the code:

```
df[total]=df['col1']+df['col2']+df['col3']+df['col4']+df['col5']
```

I know that col4 and col5 doesn't exists, I want write the code where even though col4 and col5 doesn't exits, It wont show any error, Rather I will add zero in the equation.

So the result of the first row will be 9. With out any error. 
How to code for it ?

Comment: Hmm why not `df.sum('columns')`?

Comment: @miradulo you mean axis=1?

Comment: @coldspeed Sometimes the string is nice to avoid the follow up question of "what is `axis=1`"

Comment: @miradulo Just tried it, I had no idea you could specify axis=1 as a string called 'column'... nice!

Comment: I want row wise sum. For example the result of first row will be 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `reindex`, NaNs do not count towards the sum (in DataFrames):

```
col_list = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5']
df.reindex(col_list, axis=1).sum(axis=1)
```

This is only under the assumption that, for whatever reason, `df.sum(axis=1)` isn't applicable.

Comment: This solution is giving column-wise sum, I want row-wise Sum.

Comment: getting same result. See my example carefully

Comment: @Kallol Sorry, I meant `df.reindex(col_list, axis=1).sum(axis=1)`

Comment: @colsspeed  Thanks